# How to use $min mongo query in Meteor.js?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I'm basically trying to create a filter that only displays accounts that have more than one post.

```
return tags.find([{owner: this.userId, count: { $min: 1}}]);
```

It ends up returning nothing. I tried using .min() and other stuff as well. I believe its a standard Mongo query and am wondering if there is a Meteor-specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Mongo query for that would use [`$gt`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt):

```
tags.find({owner: this.userId, count: {$gt: 1}});
```